# Exit and re-enter Schengen area if country that issued the visa is the final destination

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

I have a trip planned in February to Paris, Amsterdam, Morocco, and then Barcelona, in that order (so I enter through France, leave Schengen area to Morocco, then re-enter in Spain).

I got a Schengen visa through the Spanish consulate (technically, through BLS), but they only gave me a one-entry visa. They said that because it was issued by the Spanish consulate (Spain is where I'm going to stay the most days), I would be able to re-enter.

I would rather not have to find out at the Barcelona airport that they were mistaken, and this seems to be contrary to everything I've been reading. Can someone verify that this is the case? Or should I insist on them giving me a 2-entry visa?

Thanks!

Comment: That is also contrary to anything I’ve ever read. Who told you this exactly?

Comment: If at all possible change visa or trip. I would go for changing trip as being easiest.

Comment: The Spanish Consulate issues visas in NYC through a third party company called BLS.  They won't even let you contact the Spanish Consulate directly.  This was told to me by someone at BLS who won't let me fix the visa.

Comment: @JonathanCalindas you should call the Spanish consulate directly. If you cannot find a telephone number, write to them.  Be sure to complain not only about the incorrect visa but also about the incorrect information. You can also try to speak to a supervisor at BLS. Go as far up the chain of command as you ate able until you reach someone who acknowledges that the issued visa does not satisfy the itinerary submitted with the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoever told you this should be fired from the embassy.

The Schengen Area counts as one country for border and visa purposes: once you enter through Paris, you've used up your single entry, so after exiting through Amsterdam, you cannot go to Barcelona without a new visa.